# Stop Blazor SignalR going through Azure SignalR

Tags: blazor, signalr

I don't know if I'm thinking about this the wrong way but currently I'm using Blazor with SignalR in Azure. I can see on the live feed on Azure that ComponentHub is passing messages through, as Blazor Server uses SignalR for things such as button clicks and communicating between them both I'm just cautious that this may potentially cause more messages to be sent then I am actually using thus increasing the usage.

Am I thinking about this wrong or is there a way to only tell specific hubs to connect to Azure SignalR connection?

Comment: You should ask this question here https://github.com/azure/azure-signalr

Comment: @lebber have you made any progress or workarounds to this? We also started to utilize Azure SignalR and we are seeing a huge hit on clients/messages from what seems to be Blazor SignalR. I did end up opening an issue on the github as well since I didn't see any regarding it. [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1738)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to achieve what you're attempting - we're not using SignalR for anything else.

A couple of things from our experience though:

1. Our SignalR costs are double the app service spend for ~450 users - 20M messages per day.
2. We tried using websockets, but even on 3 instances of P3V3 app service users complained about signalr connection drop outs.
3. There's no way to save costs on SignalR - no reservations and you have no control over the messages blazor is sending.

Blazor + SignalR = Buyer Beware!!!