# Understanding SignalR, Azure and Messaging charges

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server side app, that is very small and still in development. Currently there is only myself and one user testing the app pre production.

We're using SignalR to synchronise internal printing to an on prem app even though the WebApp is hosted in Azure. Today we hit a problem with SignalR as we hit the free tier limit of 20,000 messages sent in under 24 hours. This threw me, as it's not a chat app or anything intensive. We click a button every 5-10 minutes or so and it sends a message to the SignalR hub.

On closer inspection it was clear that I wasn't disposing of the hub correctly so connections were staying open. (The component is part of a larger page)

Adding:

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable
```

and

```
public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
{
    if (hubConnection is not null)
    {
        await hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
    }
}
```

now correctly disposes of the hub when we navigate away from the page.

However, looking at the Azure logs, message count seems high. Following this process, created 200(!) messages:

1. Load the page with the component embedded
2. Press the send button twice
3. Navigate away from the page

The send button simply sends a message to the hub:

```
private async Task OnDeliveryNotePrint()
{
    // We only want to print if the order is saved.
    if (dbContext?.Entry(order!).State == EntityState.Unchanged && order != null && hubConnection != null)
    {
        await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendPrintJob", new PrintJob { TimeRequested = DateTime.Now, PrintJobType = PrintJobType.DeliveryNote, PrintJobId = order.Id });
        toastService.ShowInfo("Print job sent to the server.");
    }
    else
    {
        toastService.ShowWarning("Please save changes before printing.");
    }
}
```

Ok, my understanding might not be great, but how does this process create 200 SignalR messages? I've read the [troubleshooting page in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-guide) but can't find anything that shows me how to better understand what is happening here.

This is also where I learnt that I wasn't disposing the connection correctly and to an extent the fix has worked as the message count has dropped significantly but still, 200 messages for the above scenario feels a bit rich.

The limit on messages for the free tier (which I thought was easily accessible to us) is 20,000. At the rate the messages are being sent, it won't be and the costs can soon stack up for something we thought was really low impact.

Am I completely off-piste here and not correctly understanding the process or am I going wrong somewhere?

**UPDATE:**
I pulled the Trace Log from the signalr dashboard and the steps above indeed do creates 201 messages. The vast majority of those messages are via the `componenthub` (199) and then I can see my messages via the `printhub` (2). For an app that is so reliant on signalr it seems strange that the free tier only supports 20,000 messages. Just clicking around the app is going to exhaust this easily.

After further investigation it looks similar to [Stop Blazor SignalR going through Azure SignalR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73331916/stop-blazor-signalr-going-through-azure-signalr) and https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1738

Comment: [Do you have websockets enabled on your server?](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/48080#event-9176618832)

Comment: @JasonPan Websockets is enabled. Interestingly though, it's enabled despite documentation stating the default behaviour is disabled. I didn't enable it at any point.

Comment: Is Client Connection Count normal in metrics ?

Comment: 10 server connections, 2 client connections.

Comment: I have checked the issue, you should use higher price tier, since there is build-in Hub inside Blazor Server App, it's not a issue. You also could ask the question in github issue and verify my answer is correct.

Comment: Sounds like background job triggering Azure Function. I am curious - why do you need SignalR for async processing?

Comment: We have a blazor app and the client wants to print silently from razor pages for bulk printing. The idea was to have the server push messages to a client installed on their "printer pc" that would subsequently silently print the required record/document. I thought we could leverage signalr for this as it seemed straight forward to implement but looks like it'll come at a cost. Currently exploring other ideas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my investigation, we found that a large number of messages are generated by the communication between components, pages and state of Blazor Server itself. [This is by design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0#blazor-startup).

We can monitor the messages details by enable [Live Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-troubleshoot-live-trace) in azure portal.

Comment: Yep, I would concur after delving deeper. Thanks for your input and back to the drawing board.